# XML Choices in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap, lxml

I'm new to XML and working on a project with multiple XML Parent and Child combinations and choices. I am confused about how to conditionally select the choices from each of the `TaskID`, `PAReportDefinition` and `RiskReportsDefinition`. I have tried to nest the  parent and children with multiple combinations, but I am meeting the "Remote exception: The data node was not found: [name = a, owner = b] when I execute the below code.

```
        <wsdl:operation name="RetrieveTemplateReports">
            <wsdl:input message="bdt:RetrieveTemplateReportsInput"/>
            <wsdl:output message="bdt:RetrieveTemplateReportsOutput"/>
        </wsdl:operation>



            <xsd:element name="RetrieveTemplateReportsRequest">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="User" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Client" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xsd:element name = "RetrieveReportsInputParams" type="bdt:RetrieveReportsInputParams" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>


            <xsd:complexType name="RetrieveReportsInputParams" >
                <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:element name="TaskId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PAReportDefinition" type="bdt:ReturnAttribution" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="RiskReportsDefinition" type="bdt:RiskReportsDefinition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:element name="ReportParametersList" type ="bdt:ReportParametersDef" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xsd:element name="ReportTemplate" type ="bdt:ReportTemplate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>


            <xsd:complexType name="ReportTemplate">
                <xsd:attribute name = "TemplateName" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="TemplateOwner" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
```

I'm probably overlooking something very simple, but have been stuck on this for some time. Code below:

```py
def retrieve_template_reports(username, client_id, password,task_id, template_owner, template_name):
  """

  """
  # retrieve_template_reports = B1Client.get_type('ns0:RetrieveTemplateReports')
  # retrieve_template_reports_request =  B1Client.get_type('RetrieveTemplateReportsRequest')
  report_input_parameters = B1Client.get_type('ns0:RetrieveReportsInputParams')
  report_template = B1Client.get_type('ns0:ReportTemplate')
  report_template_factory =  report_template(TemplateName = template_name, TemplateOwner = template_owner)
  report_input_parameter_factory = report_input_parameters(TaskId = task_id, ReportTemplate = report_template_factory)
  return B1Client.service.RetrieveTemplateReports(username, client_id, password, report_input_parameter_factory)



task_id = "randombase64encodedstring"
user_id = ''
client_id = ''
password = ''
template_name = ''
template_owner = ''
wsdl = "random.wsdl"
B1Client = zeep.Client(wsdl = wsdl)


output = retrieve_template_reports(user_id,
                                   client_id,
                                   password,
                                   task_id,
                                   template_name,
                                   template_owner)
```

The end goal is to return the template reports based on the TemplateName and TemplateOwner, through the RetrieveTemplateReports parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data seems more complex than what you are showing in the code, so:

- Take your WSDL file and feed it to [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/). SoapUI can then create sample requests for your operations. You can then see in the sample request all of the parameters and how you need to structure them.
- Once you have that, you can build the parameters to call the operation. The cleanest, more readable and more maintainable way to send the parameters will be [with a dictionary](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html) instead of creating objects from types defined in the XSD schema.
- Make sure you also run [`python -mzeep ...`](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/in_depth.html) with your WSDL to view of all available operations and their call signatures.
- try using a HTTP monitor to send the calls to and see if the SOAP messages zeep generates have the proper structure (as defined by the WSDL and seen in the sample requests from the first point). SoapUI can also help with the [monitoring](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/monitoring.html).
- troubleshoot until you get a successful call.